# KVM won't do L1D flush

Tags: c, assembly, linux-kernel, intel, kvm

I am currently trying to test the performance of Intel-KVM's L1D flush functionality. In the source code (https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/arch/x86/kvm/vmx/vmx.c), the part that handles L1D_flush is as follows:

```
/*
 * Software based L1D cache flush which is used when microcode providing
 * the cache control MSR is not loaded.
 *
 * The L1D cache is 32 KiB on Nehalem and later microarchitectures, but to
 * flush it is required to read in 64 KiB because the replacement algorithm
 * is not exactly LRU. This could be sized at runtime via topology
 * information but as all relevant affected CPUs have 32KiB L1D cache size
 * there is no point in doing so.
 */
static noinstr void vmx_l1d_flush(struct kvm_vcpu *vcpu)
{
    int size = PAGE_SIZE << L1D_CACHE_ORDER;

    printk(KERN_INFO "vmx_l1d_flush triggered!\n");

    /*
     * This code is only executed when the flush mode is 'cond' or
     * 'always'
     */
    if (static_branch_likely(&vmx_l1d_flush_cond)) {
        bool flush_l1d;

        /*
         * Clear the per-vcpu flush bit, it gets set again
         * either from vcpu_run() or from one of the unsafe
         * VMEXIT handlers.
         */
        flush_l1d = vcpu->arch.l1tf_flush_l1d;

        // Make every flush happen
        vcpu->arch.l1tf_flush_l1d = true;

        /*
         * Clear the per-cpu flush bit, it gets set again from
         * the interrupt handlers.
         */
        flush_l1d |= kvm_get_cpu_l1tf_flush_l1d();
        kvm_clear_cpu_l1tf_flush_l1d();

        if (!flush_l1d)
            return;
    }

    vcpu->stat.l1d_flush++;

    if (static_cpu_has(X86_FEATURE_FLUSH_L1D)) {
        native_wrmsrl(MSR_IA32_FLUSH_CMD, L1D_FLUSH);
        return;
    }

    asm volatile(
        /* First ensure the pages are in the TLB */
        "xorl   %%eax, %%eax\n"
        ".Lpopulate_tlb:\n\t"
        "movzbl (%[flush_pages], %%" _ASM_AX "), %%ecx\n\t"
        "addl   $4096, %%eax\n\t"
        "cmpl   %%eax, %[size]\n\t"
        "jne    .Lpopulate_tlb\n\t"
        "xorl   %%eax, %%eax\n\t"
        "cpuid\n\t"
        /* Now fill the cache */
        "xorl   %%eax, %%eax\n"
        ".Lfill_cache:\n"
        "movzbl (%[flush_pages], %%" _ASM_AX "), %%ecx\n\t"
        "addl   $64, %%eax\n\t"
        "cmpl   %%eax, %[size]\n\t"
        "jne    .Lfill_cache\n\t"
        "lfence\n"
        :: [flush_pages] "r" (vmx_l1d_flush_pages),
            [size] "r" (size)
        : "eax", "ebx", "ecx", "edx");
        
        printk(KERN_INFO "vmx_l1d_flush ended!\n");
}
```

Note that I put `printk()` in some places to track the progress (where it might be stuck, etc.)

Here is where this function is called:

```
static noinstr void vmx_vcpu_enter_exit(struct kvm_vcpu *vcpu,
                    struct vcpu_vmx *vmx,
                    unsigned long flags)
{
    guest_state_enter_irqoff();
    /* L1D Flush includes CPU buffer clear to mitigate MDS */
    if (static_branch_unlikely(&vmx_l1d_should_flush))
        vmx_l1d_flush(vcpu);
    else if (static_branch_unlikely(&mds_user_clear))
        mds_clear_cpu_buffers();
    else if (static_branch_unlikely(&mmio_stale_data_clear) &&
         kvm_arch_has_assigned_device(vcpu->kvm))
        mds_clear_cpu_buffers();

    vmx_disable_fb_clear(vmx);

    if (vcpu->arch.cr2 != native_read_cr2())
        native_write_cr2(vcpu->arch.cr2);

    vmx->fail = __vmx_vcpu_run(vmx, (unsigned long *)&vcpu->arch.regs,
                   flags);

    vcpu->arch.cr2 = native_read_cr2();
    .... (Skipping the rest of the lines since they're not the issue)
```

According to this doc (https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/admin-guide/hw-vuln/l1tf.html#mitigation-control-kvm), I attempted to set the Intel-KVM module parameters "vmentry_l1d_flush" to always, but the function did not trigger. In `/sys/modules/kvm_intel/parameters/vmentry_l1d_flush`, It still says "not required".

Then, I decided to change the code, by-pass the check and manually trigger `vmx_l1d_flush()`. It does trigger, but it never exits (and the VM will also be stuck with black screen, before even showing up BIOS setup). After some debugging, I realized that it is stuck inside the in-line assembly, and it is stuck in the first half of the in-line assembly (before the /Now fill the cache/ comment).

I am not sure why this is happening. I will keep reading the KVM documentation to try to understand where the problem might be, but I would appreciate any help or hint for a way to tackle this problem. Thank you!

P.S, my CPU is Intel(R) Xeon(R) Platinum 8358P CPU @ 2.60GHz, X86_64

Comment: Did you check what the value of `size` is? What happens if you only leave the `xor eax, eax; cpuid` and remove everything else?

Comment: @Jester Hi! I've re-run the code, `size` is 65536, and if I remove everything except `xor eax, eax` and `cpuid`, it will run without any issue.

Comment: Okay so that is fine. The code is of course just reading 64k from `vmx_l1d_flush_pages` maybe look at that next. In particular it seems to be initialized from line 286 onwards but only conditionally. Verify that allocation is in fact executed.

Comment: As Jester said the buffer may not be allocated yet or `vmx_l1d_flush` may not be designed to be called from arbitrary places. Since you already have the debugging and compiling machinery in place it may be better to check why the function is not called. It may be you have an updated microcode that provides the MSR referenced in the first line of the comment. In this case comment out that fast path and KVM should revert to the slow in-software flush.

Comment: what does `cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/vulnerabilities/l1tf` output?

Comment: @k1r1t0 It says "not affected". I didn't realize you can check l1tf this way, I'll have to check more on that.